# What minerals found in tap water harm dracaena plants?

Tags: watering, dracaena

I've heard dracaena need filtered water to live indoors because some compounds in tap water will kill them off. I also know that what's in your tap water can depend on where you live and leaving water out overnight can allow some compounds to evaporate. However, I don't know what dracaena plants react to, and I'd like to know so I can determine if there's a safe way to use my tap water.

Comment: I have lived about 5 different places ( 5 different water types) with dracaenas and never found them to be sensitive to water chemistry. Generally the only thing that comes out  in several hours is "chlorine" ( actually various materials used by municipalities for water treatment ). I rely on this process for my aquarium water.  Other gases will exchange ( oxygen, nitrogen, and carbon dioxide ) but the amounts in water will not affect plants.

Answer (score 1):

Like you say already, it depends on where you live and what chemicals are present in your tap water.

Mostly, *Draceana* are sensitive to chlorine and fluoride. Chlorine is found almost in all tap waters, and can evaporate (since it is a dissolved gas). However, fluoride is an ion (salt), and will not evaporate. But luckily fluoride is not found in all tap waters.

Another usual suspect is Calcium (lime). It can deposit as Calcium carbonate, and can therefore disturb the functioning of the roots in the soil.

What I would advice, is to buy some demineralized water. You can buy it at the supermarket or drugstore. Try to give that only for a while and see if it helps your plant to recover.